# $\lim_{x\to\infty} K_{ij}(x) = 0$ BUT $\lim_{x\to\infty} ||K(x)||_{F} = \sqrt{n-1}$ !!!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

I have a real square full-rank matrix $K$ of size $n\times n$, where each entry of this matrix is a function of a real variable $x$. As I compute numerically the limit as $x \to \infty$, every entry goes to zero, which is what I expect, knowing pretty well the form of my matrix entries (essentially, these are all exponentials of negative arguments). However, and this is what I find mindblowing, taking the limit of the Frobenius norm of my matrix, what I get is not $0$, as I'd expect, but exactly $\sqrt{n-1}$. How's that even possible or is there just some mistake in my code ?!!

Comment: $||A|| = 0$ iff $a_{ij} = 0$ by def. of matrix norm.  I think you have a bug.

Comment: You can’t tell us more about $K_{ij}(x)?$ As stated, it seems like you’ve made an error somewhere, but we can’t help you find your error without more details.

Comment: The matrix is obtained after many many operations of multiplications, inverses, transactions, etc. so expressing this matrix explicitly would be pretty much impossible. However, what I know for sure, is the elements of this matrix ain't nothing but intricate combinations of exponentials, such as $e^{-x}, e^{-nx}, e^{-(2n+1)x}$, etc.

Comment: Yes, BadAtMath, that I'm certain. However, we're not in the finite case here ! Is this happening because of the infinitely big size $n$ of the matrix ? My code seems perfect so far. Something tells me it's due to the super large value of $n$ (about $10^{20}$). My intuition is based on what we know about the permutation of the integral and the summation over an integer $n$. See, if the summation is finite, we can definitely do that. However, if the summation is INFINITE, in this case, we cannot do that unless the uniform convergence of the series is established.

Comment: Ah.  Ok @Mokrane then may I suggest you look at the spectrum of your operator via a method that's useful for large matrices, e.g. a Krylov method.

Comment: I'm going to get on my high horse here for a minute (sorry), having done numerical work for 30+ years.  IMHO, you need to look at your operator using tools that will work to learn what you can (e.g. GMRES, SVD, etc..).  Then, armed with that knowledge, you will be able to make sense of your Frobenius norm.   Perhaps as was hinted in the answer below, you are simultaneously taking limits in such a way to yield the result you have observed.  Hope that helps

Comment: Infinitely big matrix? Even with $n$ about $10^{20},$ it is finite. It is just not possible for a finite matrix to have entries approaching zero and Frobenius norm not approaching zero.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\|K(x)\|_F^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}K_{i,j}(x)^2,$$ we have $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\|K(x)\|_F^2 = \lim_{x \to \infty}\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}K_{i,j}(x)^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\lim_{x \to \infty}K_{i,j}(x)^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}0 = 0,$$ where the interchange of the limit and summation is valid since the sum has finitely many terms. So what you are describing is impossible.

If you were taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ instead of $x \to \infty$, i.e., the matrix was growing in size, then it would be possible to have each entry of the matrix tend to $0$, but the Frobenius norm grow.

Comment: Thank you!! No, the limit is $x \to \infty$, however the size $n$ is huge, about $10^{20}$. So is it because the fact we can't interchange unless we establish uniform convergence of the quantity inside ?

Comment: No, the interchange works fine. @Mokrane Another way of looking at it is, finite sums are always uniform convergent.